# Linux: How does communication with kernel module from user space happen

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am reading Embedded Linux Primer book and The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide and I am confused about user space application communication with kernel module

User space App -->  Device node/proc file --> kernel module ( which resides in /lib/modules/)

1) What is exact difference when we communicate with device node method ( /dev/ - with open,read,write,close calls) and /proc/file method ?

Comment: Ask this question here :  http://unix.stackexchange.com/   ..It is all about linux

Answer (score 0):

`procfs` (`/proc`) should be reserved for process information a module should not put any file there. At some point, `procfs` was the only available pseudo filesystem, that is why you can find sound system or RTC information. Then, `sysfs` was created to properly contain those information.

The main difference between using a device file (usually residing in /dev) and a file from procfs is the way it is handled in the kernel.

Operations used for the device files are registered using the [file_operations](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1602) structure usually with `cdev_init` and `cdev_add` for a character device. Your module may not do that as quite often, the subsytem is the one registering your device.

While the operations for files in `procfs` are registered using [proc_create](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h#L30)